# Find anagrams of a given word in a file

Tags: python, string, file, text, anagram

Alright so for class we have this problem where we need to be able to input a word and from a given text file (wordlist.txt) a list will be made using any anagrams of that word found in the file.

My code so far looks like this:

```
def find_anagrams1(string):
"""Takes a string and returns a list of anagrams for that string from the wordlist.txt file.

string -> list"""
anagrams = []

file = open("wordlist.txt")
next = file.readline()
while next != "":
    isit = is_anagram(string, next)
    if isit is True:
        anagrams.append(next)
    next = file.readline()
file.close()

return anagrams
```

Every time I try to run the program it just returns an empty list, despite the fact that I know there are anagrams present. Any ideas on what's wrong?

P.S. The is_anagram function looks like this:

```
def is_anagram(string1, string2):
"""Takes two strings and returns True if the strings are anagrams of each other.

list,list -> string"""
a = sorted(string1)
b = sorted(string2)
if a == b:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

I am using Python 3.4

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304231/finding-anagrams-of-a-string-in-python

Comment: I think newline character might be causing the issue. You need to remove it from the end of line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `readline` function.  From the documentation:

```
file.readline = readline(...)
readline([size]) -> next line from the file, as a string.

Retain newline.  A non-negative size argument limits the maximum
number of bytes to return (an incomplete line may be returned then).
Return an empty string at EOF.
```

The key information here is "Retain newline".  That means that if you have a file containing a list of words, one per line, each word is going to be returned with a terminal newline.  So when you call:

```
next = file.readline()
```

You're not getting `example`, you're getting `example\n`, so this will never match your input string.

A simple solution is to call the `strip()` method on the lines read from the file:

```
next = file.readline().strip()
while next != "":
    isit = is_anagram(string, next)
    if isit is True:
        anagrams.append(next)
    next = file.readline().strip()
file.close()
```

However, there are several problems with this code.  To start with, `file` is a terrible name for a variable, because this will mask the python `file` module.

Rather than repeatedly calling `readline()`, you're better off taking advantage of the fact that an open file is an iterator which yields the lines of the file:

```
words = open('wordlist.txt')
for word in words:
    word = word.strip()
    isit = is_anagram(string, word)
    if isit:
      anagrams.append(word)
words.close()
```

Note also here that since `is_anagram` returns True or False, you
don't need to compare the result to `True` or `False` (e.g., `if isit
is True`).  You can simply use the return value on its own.

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you so much, this was incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Yikes, don't use for loops:

```
import collections

def find_anagrams(x):
    anagrams = [''.join(sorted(list(i))) for i in x]
    anagrams_counts = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(anagrams).items() if count > 1]
    return [i for i in x if ''.join(sorted(list(i))) in anagrams_counts]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, that I think is quite elegant. This runs in O(n * m) where n is the number of words and m is number of letters (or average number of letters/word).

```
# anagarams.py

from collections import Counter
import urllib.request


def word_hash(word):
  return frozenset(Counter(word).items())

def download_word_file():
  url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/first20hours/google-10000-english/master/google-10000-english-no-swears.txt'
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'words.txt')

def read_word_file():
  with open('words.txt') as f:
    words = f.read().splitlines()
  return words


if __name__ == "__main__":
  # downloads a file to your working directory
  download_word_file()

  # reads file into memory
  words = read_word_file()

  d = {}

  for word in words:
    k = word_hash(word)
    if k in d:
      d[k].append(word)
    else:
      d[k] = [word]

  # Prints the filtered results to only words with anagrams
  print([x for x in d.values() if len(x) > 1])
```