# Read file and find anagrams in it

Tags: python, file

I have a problem in which i need to find all the anagrams in a file.

I know how to find anagrams and i am using sorted() function to do it.

My problem is i have to find it in a file. File has 4000 line and each line has only one word.

The logic i am using is two open the file twice using 2 file pointers say fp1 and fp2.
Then i use nested for loop and for each word in fp1 i compare it with each word in fp2 using sorted function. I do get the output, but since it is 4000 words and two file pointers, it becomes very slow.

If i try to read the whole file once and store in list, the scripts hangs.

Is there any better way to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

I have added the code:

```py
def isPalindrome(filepo):
 count=0
 for word in filepo:
     word=word.strip()
     if(word==word[::-1]):
         count=count+1
         print (word + " is palindrome")
 print( count)

def isAnagram(fp1,fp2):
   anagramcount=0
   for word in fp1:
     anagramlist=[]
     word=word.strip()
     for secword in fp2:
         secword=secword.strip()
         if(word != secword):
             if(sorted(word)==sorted(secword)):
                 anagramlist.append(secword)
     fp2.close()
     fp2=open("English.txt",'r')
     if(len(anagramlist)>0):
         anagramcount=anagramcount+1
         #print(word+ " is an anagram with possible combinations:")
         #for x in anagramlist:
             #print(x)
 print("Total anagrams are: ",anagramcount)
file1=open("English.txt",'r')
isPalindrome(file1)
file1.close()
file2=open("English.txt",'r')
file3=open("English.txt",'r')
isAnagram(file2,file3)
```

I can read the file at once, but since file is big with 4000 lines it become slow. is there any good way to make it fast

Comment: I was wondering if you could provide us with your short and runnable working code. That would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find anagrams of a given word in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868716/find-anagrams-of-a-given-word-in-a-file)

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load all the words in a dictionary keyed on the sorted letters of each word.  Then only keep entries with more than one word in them.

```
anagrams = dict()
for word in wordList:  # list loaded from the file (or read lines directly from file)
    anagrams.setdefault(sorted(word),[]).append(word)
anagrams = [ words for words in anagrams.values() if len(words)>1 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the file using enumerate;. 
make two lists,. 
  one for the words. 
  one for (sortedword, index) tuples;. 
sort the tuple list;. 
use itertools.groupby on the tuple list to get the indices of anagrams;. 
use these on the word list

Or create a dictionary while iterating over the file. Use the sorted word for the keys and  a list for each value, appending each word to the value for its key.